# JES Shrinking Algorithm Not Working

Tags: python, algorithm, jython, jes

I'm trying to write a simple algorithm to halve the size of a picture, it seems to make sense to me, but I'm probably missing something obvious here, and was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
a = pickAFile()
b = makePicture(a)
c = getWidth(b)
d = getHeight(b)
e = (c * 3) / 4
f = (d * 3) / 4
canvas = makeEmptyPicture(e,f)
sourceX = 1
for targetX in range (1, c):
  sourceY = 1
  for targetY in range (1, d):
    color = getColor(getPixel(b, sourceX, sourceY))
    setColor(getPixel(canvas, targetX, targetY), color)
    sourceY = sourceY + 2
    sourceX = sourceX + 2
show(canvas)
show(b)
```

EDIT: When I try to run it as it is now, I get a index out of bounds error for the for loops.

Comment: I don't know what is JES and I don'know much about pictures but as far as I can see you want to create a new picture (target picture) by copying every source pixel with odd coordinates (x and y coordinate from 1,3,5,...). I think e and f are the height and width of the target picture. Why is e = (c * 3) / 4 and not something like   e=c/2  and f=d/2 if the target picture has half width and half height? Why does targetX run from 1 to c and target y form 1 to d? I would suspect that targetX should run from 1 to e (thats about c/2). But maybe I have to less knowledge of the involved topics

Comment: I am sure that there is something out of bound but what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

To start with the dimensions of canvas should be half the original image. So you should change

```
e = (c * 3) / 4
f = (d * 3) / 4
```

to

```
e = c / 2
f = d / 2
```

Secondly the for loops are meant to iterate from the the first pixel of the new image to the the last. Please change the following

```
for targetX in range (1, c):
```

to

```
for targetX in range (1, e):
```

and

```
for targetY in range (1, d):
```

to

```
for targetY in range (1, f):
```

The next problem is that you increment the variable sourceX inside the inner for loop. You will need to change the indent for this line code so it is part of the outer for loop

The complete code should look like this

```
a = pickAFile()
b = makePicture(a)
c = getWidth(b)
d = getHeight(b)
e = c / 2
f = d / 2
canvas = makeEmptyPicture(e,f)
sourceX = 1
for targetX in range (1, e):
  sourceY = 1
  for targetY in range (1, f):
    color = getColor(getPixel(b, sourceX, sourceY))
    setColor(getPixel(canvas, targetX, targetY), color)
    sourceY = sourceY + 2
  sourceX = sourceX + 2
show(canvas)
show(b)
```

The last thing I recommend is for you choose more meaningful names for your variables. Nameing c and e, sourceWidth and targetWidth respectively would have helped you identify the problem with the for loops a lot easier. It would have also taken you less time to type a few extra keys then the time spent trying to find the problems within the code.